# JavaFX Bind Label textProperty to multiple Properties changes

Tags: java, javafx, binding

**What i want to do is:**

I have a JavaFX Window which i am constantly changing the width and height of it by dragging the `corners or the sides`.`I want when the width or height are changing` then the text of the `Label` to have the below format:

```
~Width=[here the width of the Window],Height[here the height of the Window]~
```

Example:

```
~Width=[1300],Height=[600]~
```

---

**I want to do this using bindings and not using 2(two) `ChangeListeners`**.

```
                                   I am trying:

label.textProperty().bind(I am stack here on how to do this...);
```

I had read also this question [JavaFX bind to multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264480/javafx-bind-to-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `Bindings.createStringBinding` with both `width` and `height` as dependencies:

```
StringBinding binding = Bindings.createStringBinding(
            () -> MessageFormat.format("~Width=[{0}],Height=[{1}]~", primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight()),
            primaryStage.widthProperty(),
            primaryStage.heightProperty());

label.textProperty().bind(binding);
```

Comment: O_O Nice thank you! First time i see `MessageFormat` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use a change listener, and query the with/height values manually. Like

```
public void init()
{
     ChangeListener<Number> listener = (obs, ov, nv) -> update();
    node.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
    node.heightProperty().addListener(listener);
}

public void update()
{
      label.setText(String.format("width[%s] height[%s]", node.getWidth()), node.getHeight);
}
```